# llvm bindings in lua?

Tags: lua, llvm

Does LLVM have lua bindings?

I'm not interested in using LLVM as a backend /JIT for Lua.

I want access to LLVM through lua.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This http://code.google.com/p/luaclang/ ?

Comment: pre-alpha, but a binding is a binding +1